# Count array except the empty values

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
 var a = [{'id': 1}, {'id':''}, {'id':3}]
```

And now I need to count the array except the empty id so the answer should be 2.
I tried to used filter function but I couldn't get my expected out put.

This is the codes I am done so far.

```
         a.filter(Boolean).length; // Returns 3. It should be 2.
```

Any idea is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you explain what `a.filter(Boolean).length;` is trying to do?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the documentation. You don't place the literal word "Boolean" as the argument for `filter`. You pass something that returns true or false depending on whether you keep or exclude each item in the array. By passing `Boolean`, you're simply returning a non-false value for every element, so it doesn't work.

Try this example out to understand filter better: https://codepen.io/garethredfern/pen/zBLLYW

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Your array
const arr = [{'id': 1}, {'id':''}, {'id':3}]

// Filter returns a new array with elements that match the condition below
const length = arr.filter( element => element.id != "" ).length;

console.log(length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const array = [{'id': 1}, {'id':''}, {'id':3}]

const count = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
 if (cur.id !== '') {
   acc += 1
 }
 return acc
}, 0)

console.log(count)
```

`array.filter(Boolean).length` is returns 3 because [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns elements if provider returns true, In your case, passing object to `Boolean`({...}) which returns true, so it keeps all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
const length = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arr).filter(([_, v]) => v.id != '')).length;
```

console.log(length);

You can also use `Object.fromEntries` to bypass object element that does not match